# dynamically choose fields from different table based on existense

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables A and B.

1. Both the tables have same number of columns.
2. Table A always contains all ids of Table B.
3. Need to fetch row from Table B first if it does not exist then have
   to fetch from Table A.

I was trying to dynamically do this

```
select 
      CASE
      WHEN b.id is null THEN
         a.*
      ELSE
         b.*
      END
from A a
left join B b on b.id = a.id
```

I think this syntax is not correct.

Can some one suggest how to proceed.

Comment: You have the right idea. You can't use `*` though, you have to list every column in it's own `CASE` expression. Also, instead of `CASE` you can use `COALESCE()` like `SELECT COALESCE(a.id, b.id) as id, COALESCE(a.foo, b.foo) as foo, COALESCE(a.bar, b.bar) as bar FROM A a
left join B b on b.id = a.id `

Comment: @JNevill. Thanks for quick note. Is there any better approach instead of checking field by field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to select all columns from table A except when a matching ID exists in table B.  In that case you want to select all columns from table B.

That can be done with this query as long as the number and types of columns in both tables are compatible:

```
select * from a where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id)
union all
select * from b
```

If the number, types, or order of columns differs you will need to explicitly specify the columns to return in each sub query.

Comment: Awesome. This is what I was looking for. Very helpful.